# Raspberry pi error in octave

Tags: raspberry-pi, octave

I am getting this error on octave on raspberry pi:

> Segmentation fault -- stopping myself attempting to save variables to
>   'octave-workspace' warning: unable to open 'octave-workspace' for
>   writing Segmentation fault

What does this mean?

Comment: Have you had success running octave on a pi earlier? This might be a naive question from my side, but isn't octave too heavy-weight for the specs of a pi? (You can probably tell that I'm not *that* familiar with pis)

Comment: that error means that you crashed Octave. What you did before that error appeared is what's important.

Comment: Which RPi (1 or 2), which OS (Rapbian?), GNU Octave from repo and what did you execute before the segfault happened?